# vcpkg could not locate a manifest (vcpkg.json)

Tags: visual-studio

The vcpkg package manager can be installed as part of Visual Studio (2022), and should be executable via the Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt, which below image proves. However, I face an error message when attempting to install a package using vcpkg. What is going wrong?

I have tried running the Developer Command Prompt as normal user or as admin. It makes no difference. This topic: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/32641, mentions that the issue is solved for some users by restarting the CLI. This does not work for me. The github issue also mentions that the issue is fixed in https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/36141. However, that one does not seem to affect vcpkg installed via Visual Studio Installer.

How can I fix this while still using the Visual Studio installed vcpkg instance?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems I needed to navigate into the folder of my Visual Studio project, then type in the following in the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022:

> vcpkg new --application

This generates a vcpkg.json and a vcpkg-configuration.json file. I can manually add the dependencies I need in the vcpkg.json file, then type the following to install them:

> vcpkg install

Here is a good tutorial that I followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/get_started/get-started?pivots=shell-cmd

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems like the one discussed in bug-report
[Running vcpkg from within cmd.exe such that vcvarsall.bat runs, installs the embedded-into-VS copy's doskey macro #32641](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/32641).

The final message in the post by developer BillyONeal from
January 2024 says:

> OK, should be fixed by [#36141](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/36141) . Thanks again!

So it seems that the latest release (or one of the next releases)
should have this problem fixed.

BillyONeal has in a previous messages detailed his analysis of
the problem, including a workaround that can serve until his fix
is released:

> I think I know what's happening now.
>
> - `vcpkg install` wants to get a compiler to use. In order to figure that out, it runs `vcvarsall.bat`
> - `vcvarsall.bat` has embedded within it the 'comes with Visual Studio' copy of vcpkg, which installs a `doskey` macro in order to
>   enable artifacts scenarios like `vcpkg use`
> - Unexpectedly, the doskey macro is being 'inherited'? by the parent process, so it leaks into the caller of `vcpkg install`
>
> Workarounds are either:
>
> - `doskey vcpkg=` to remove the macro after doing this
> - going around the doskey macro by saying `vcpkg.exe` rather than `vcpkg`
>
> I never noticed this because all my shells start with pwsh and Windows
> Terminal and apparently something in that combo causes this
> inheritance to not happen.